# Angular build monorepo into one package

Tags: angular, monorepo, nrwl-nx, ng-packagr

I am currently refactoring all of our Angular repositories into one Nx monorepo. All of the repos are libraries, and currently build into separate packages. My company would like to build these libraries into one large package as well. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use those packages as a dependency in another library and then package that library or creating different config in angular.json where you treat all files as part of one library. both ways it should do what you are looking for.